# Misconception about air pressure

Tags: pressure, air

1. I have heard that our ear pops at high altitude cause of change in air pressure, air pressure outside your eardrums needs to equalize with air pressure inside your eardrums, however, gravity pulls the air inside our ear drums with the same force it pulls air outside our ear drums, so our ears shouldn't pop?
2. If I open a bottle inside a plane at high altitude then close the bottle,at lower altitude the bottle will get crushed, however the air pressure inside the bottle should be the same as outside the bottle since gravity pulls the air inside the bottle with the same force it pulls the air molecules outside the bottle, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but there are some issues. At high altitudes, there is less air, and therefore less pressure, not because gravity is much different, but because there is less air pushing down on you. If you go to a higher altitude, the air in your ears with be at a higher pressure than the air outside and want to equalize. This happens because your ear forms sort of a pressurized seal in certain circumstances (I'm no biologist). 
As for question 2, If you open, drink, and close a drink on mount Everest (planes are usually pressurized to normal conditions), then there is less air on the inside because air is less dense at higher altitudes. Because of this, the collision of air molecules with the inside of the can (internal pressure) happens less frequently (is lower) than the outside collisions (higher pressure). This causes the can to collapse in order to equalize the pressure. Of course, this depends on the strength of the can and the change in altitude.

Comment: So basically when we open a bottle inside a plane, the air inside the bottle will be replaced by less dense air, therefore there will be less air inside the bottle compared to ground level, am i right?

Comment: Yes. Because less dense air has fewer collisions with the sides of the can (these collisions are what we call pressure), there will be lower pressure on the inside than the outside, causing the can to warp.

Answer (score 1):

The *cabin air* pressure changes with height, due to gravity.

Air pressure decreases with altitude.  This can be explained by noticing the lower you are in the atmosphere, the more air above you, which creates higher pressure.  A simplified explanation is given by the basics of [hydrostatics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrostatics).

As you rise up in the plane, the cabin air pressure decreases somewhat as the outside air pressure decreases.  The bottle, or the air that pops from your ears, are approximately *sealed containers*.  As the cabin pressure gets lower, all the pressure in the sealed containers can stay built up.

The greater the pressure difference between the two, the greater force acting on the container.  If the force gets too great, the container can pop or break.

If you seal a bottle on the ground and take it up, it will push outwards.  If you take it up open and seal it in the air, it will push inwards when you get back on the ground.  The containers allow you to make the pressure difference.